# How can I diagonally split a line separator into two colors?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have some simple graphics in Photoshop (just a styled line). But I am very confused on how to re-create it using CSS and HTML. The graphics are:

[image: First Line]

and

[image: Second Line]

I want to use them as a top border, bottom border, and maybe separator line.

Comment: Hint: [**CSS triangles**](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/)

Comment: Or `transform`s, `<canvas>`, SVG, etc.

Comment: can you give me an example of code ?

Comment: Wawan, StackOverflow is not really the place for basic, in-depth tutorials. It's more about specific problems and their solutions.

Comment: I find questions like these rather enjoyable.  Beats doing Sudoku.  Here's both left and right separator lines: http://jsfiddle.net/mvsj8ooj/.  And, a simpler solution using transforms: http://jsfiddle.net/6yj8c11z/.

Comment: You could do this using gradients without any extra elements/pseudos/transforms also like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/osbg8hvv/). Posting as comment because answers can no longer be added.

Answer (score 5):

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/1bvoze13/

HTML:

```
<div class="separator"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.separator
{
    height:10px;
    position:relative;
    background:#FF1F47;
}

div.separator::before, div.separator::after
{
    content:'';
    border:solid;
    border-width:0 0 10px 10px;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-bottom-color:red;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}

div.separator::before
{
    border-bottom-color:white;
    right:10px;
}

div.separator::after
{
    border-bottom-color:#1BB4DA;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, because it will work in older browsers.  There is a more efficient approach if transforms can be employed: http://jsfiddle.net/6yj8c11z/.

Answer (score 1):

[Check the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv1pnkvL/)

### HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="white"></div>
    <div id="red"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    min-height:50px;
}
#blue {
    width:70%;
    min-height:10px;
    background-color:turquoise;
    float:left;
}
#blue::after{
    
position:absolute;
content:"";
left:69%;    
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px 50px 0 0;
border-color: turquoise transparent transparent transparent;
    
}
#white {
    width:10%;
    min-height:10px;
    background-color:#fff;
        float:left;
}
#red {
    width:20%;
    min-height:10px;
    background-color:#FF0000;
        float:left;
}
#red::before{
position:absolute;
content:"";
left:75%;    
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 0 10px 50px;
border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
    
}
```